Решить систему линейных уравнений при известных x и y
Есть две точки с известными координатами.
Нужна формула прямой, на которой лежат эти точки. Данный вопрос решается системой линейных уравнений. Много примеров такого решения от numpy либо scipy при известных k и b и неизвестных x и y, но у меня ситуация противоположная.  Формула прямой, напомню y = kx + b.
Искал, но не нашёл готовое решение.
Есть ли такое?

Ну замените x и y в этом уравнении на что-то другое, а k и b назовите x и y. Суть от этого не поменяется, но может так будет удобнее.

Да прямо подставьте ваши две точки по очереди в формулу. Получится два уравнения. Потом подумайте как из ваших уравнений по очереди получить k и b. Это очень просто.

Причём тут система линейных уравнений не догадался. Это уравнение прямой, проходящей через заданные две точки.

Готовый консольный скрипт (сохраните в файл .py и запустите)
import os

print("-" * 50 + "\nУравнение прямой, проходящей через две заданные точки:\n" + "-" * 50)

def line_equation(x1, y1, x2, y2):
 if x1 == x2: return f"x = {x1}" # Вертикальная линия
 elif y1 == y2: return f"y = {y1}" # Горизонтальная линия
 else:
  slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
  intercept = y1 - slope * x1
  return f"y = {slope}x + {intercept}"

# Пример использования:
x1, y1 = -1, 2
x2, y2 = 4, 3

print("Точки:", f"A({x1}, {y1}) и B({x2}, {y2})")
print("Уравнение:", line_equation(x1, y1, x2, y2))

print("\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul" if os.name == "nt" else "read > /dev/null")


Подставили координаты первой точки, записали уравнение, подставили координаты второй, записали ещё одно. Решили относительно неизвестных k, b.
Особый вид уравнений позволяет это сделать чуть проще, чем для произвольной системы.
y1 = k*x1 + b
y2 = k*x2 + b

вычтем
y1-y2 = k*(x1-x2)   
k = (y1-y2) / (x1-x2)   

и теперь
b = y1 - (y1-y2) / (x1-x2) * x1        

